# upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am deploying a virtual service and gateway but when I run it on browser get the below error:

**upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure**

I deployed with helm chart and the result of dry run is below for virtual service and gateway:

```
# Source: beta-optimus/templates/gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: beta-api-dev-gateway
spec:
  selector: 
      istio: ingressgateway
  servers: 
    - port:
         number: 443
         name: https
         protocol: HTTP
      hosts: 
         - "*.myapp.xyz"
---
# Source: beta-optimus/templates/virtualService.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: beta-api-dev
spec:
  hosts:
    - "beta-api-dev.myapp.xyz"
  gateways: 
    - beta-api-dev-gateway
  http:
    - route:
         - destination: 
               host: beta-optimus
```

the beta-optimus is running on 2 pods fine.
I am using AWS so I made entry into Route53 for the proposed URL with istio. My other deployments work fine, but getting the error only in this one.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. The Service port needed a name added to it. https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19966. Make sure your *beta-optimus* service port has a name.

https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/

```
ports:
    - name: https # Use http or https
       protocol: TCP
       port: 8080
       targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: I already have named the port, the issue is that this is golang application and internally it uses grpc for communication.